# show the selected radio button and hide all others

Tags: jquery, html, css, radio-button

I am trying to make the selected radio button hide all unselected radio buttons?. The way i am thinking is first get the radiobutton selected and unselect each of the other buttons with their id's. But is there any other way than this? (I think fetching each id's and unselecting is bit cumbersome)

Here is my html

```
<form>
      <group class="inline-radio">
        <div>
          <input id="opt1" type="radio" name="title">
          <label>opt1</label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input id="opt2" type="radio" name="title" checked>
          <label>opt2</label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input id="opt3" type="radio" name="title">
          <label>opt3</label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input id="opt4" type="radio" name="title">
          <label>opt4</label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input id="opt5" type="radio" name="title">
          <label>others</label>
        </div>
      </group>

</form>
```

The project is in codepen http://codepen.io/flyingboy007/pen/ojoVWe

Comment: How are your users supposed to change their chosen option in this situation? Also, please post your JavaScript (and your [MCVE]) *here* in your question; don't expect people to traipse around the internet for the joy of doing you a favour. Incidentally, there is no `<group>` element; you may be thinking of - or meaning to use - [`<fieldset>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset). And, further, a `<label>` is meant to be associated with a given `<input>` (etc) element, whether that element is nested within the `<label>` or identified by the `for` attribute.

Comment: i dont have it.. I just need some suggestions based on the html provided. so that i can write the jquery part

Comment: Then I think you have the site backwards; you should try to implement a solution and *then* ask for help if the attempted solution doesn't work or fails in some way (explaining what it *should* do, what it *doesn't* do etc).

Comment: The solution in my mind i clearly mentioned in question. But i didnt think it is the best approach and thats why i didnt implement it. and posted it here to get some insight..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can hide the unselected radios using:-

```
$('input[type="radio"]').not(':checked').hide();
```

and you can hide the unselected radios label's using

```
$('input[type="radio"]').not(':checked').siblings('label').hide();
```

though you should use [**for**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label#attr-for) on the label.

**Edit**

To be more specific to that group, use:-

```
$('group.inline-radio').find('input[type="radio"]').not(':checked').hide();

$('group.inline-radio').find('input[type="radio"]').not(':checked').siblings('label').hide();
```

Or chained for the radio and label

```
$('group.inline-radio').find('input[type="radio"]').not(':checked').hide().siblings('label').hide();
```

Comment: just a quick doubt..I want the selected radio button to float to left side(in the place of the first radio button) while hiding others. is there any jquery methods available for that??

Comment: use css - float:left; the container divs around the input/label have widths which keep them from going left. set the widths on the labels instead of the containers.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('input ').on('click',function(){
    $('input').not($(this)).hide();
});
```

On click select all inputs except the selected one and hides tham

Comment: Please take the time to explain how this works, in order that the OP - and future visitors - might be able to learn something useful from it.